# TensorFlow Estimator to TensorFlow JS

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflowjs-converter

With the help of the Stack Overflow community, I have started to understand the complexity of TensorFlow's "high level" API, `Estimator`. I, perhaps foolishly, did so thinking that if TensorFlow and TensorFlow JS were to get along, most likely it would be through the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimators) API...

So in this [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub), I have a simple custom [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators) which is simply wired up so that methods like `.train_and_evaluate` work and after "training" the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimators) is exported via `export_savedmodel`.

Now, suppose I want to go ahead and use this trained model in the browser via TensorFlow js.

To my luck, there is a [guide](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-saved-model.html) on how to convert a `saved_model` for TensorFlow JS:

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --output_node_names='MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1' \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    /mobilenet/saved_model \
    /mobilenet/web_model
```

While the arguments have a description...

- `--output_node_names` The names of the output nodes, separated by commas.
- `--saved_model_tags`  Only applicable to SavedModel conversion, Tags of the MetaGraphDef to load, in comma separated format. Defaults to serve.
- `--signature_name`    Only applicable to TensorFlow Hub module conversion, signature to load. Defaults to default. See https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_signatures/.

I am not sure what I am supposed to replace these with for the demo estimator found in the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub).

Why? Well for starters, the `best_model` exporter, which uses the `serving_input_receiver_fn`, has different output when loaded via

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model('<exported_location>')
```

than from

```
estimator.predict(lambda: predict_input_fn(pred_features), yield_single_examples=False)
```

namely, the key of the predicted features features outputted in the former is "outputs" and "labels" in the latter.

which, forgive my mini-rant, why doesn't `Estimator` have a way to load an exported model?

so:

1. what are my "`output_node_names`"?
2. since this is a SavedModel, what `tags` do I need?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance.